# Can't find my styles in silverlight 5

Tags: silverlight, xaml

I have several styles on my silverlight project in a file named "Styles.xaml" as shown here :
[image]

But when i try to use it on my views i get this error message :
[image]

So i went to the 'Properties' window and noticed visual studio is not recognizing my styles :
[image]

The code of my style :

```
    <Style x:Key="RemoveDialogButtonStyle" TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource BotaoBasicoCsla}">
    <Setter Property="Content" Value="Remover" />
    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="17"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Image Source="/Prolex.Net.Protesto;component/Images/Remove.png" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Column="0" />
                    <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="1"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Any idea why i cant use then as StaticResource?

Comment: Did you work out what the problem was?  I'm getting the same issue.

Comment: I had to create a resource dictionary on each view.

Answer (score 0):

Is Styles.xaml referenced in App.xaml?

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Assets/Styles.xaml"/> 
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>                
</Application.Resources>
```